# SFRA - Cartridge for payment methods returning an empty list

Tags: javascript, controller, b2c

I'm currently exploring how to extend Salesforce's API. I currently have a Controller that tries to retrieve the payment methods available. The problem is that it's returning an empty list. There are payment methods associated with the sandbox site so I think that's not the problem.

This is my endpoint:

```
server.get('List',
userLoggedIn.validateLoggedIn,
function (req, res, next) {

    var PaymentMgr = require('dw/order/PaymentMgr');
    var paymentMethods = PaymentMgr.getActivePaymentMethods();

    if (paymentMethods === undefined || paymentMethods === null) {
        res.json({
            message: 'fail'
        });
    } else {
        res.json({
            paymentMethods
        });
    }
    
    next();
});
```

This is the response i'm getting:

{
"action": "PaymentMethods-List",
"queryString": "lang=default",
"locale": "default",
"paymentMethods": {}
}

And these are the payment methods:

[image: Payment Methods]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out an answer. The problem was that the res.json was not able to parse the object paymentMethods. I had to iterate through the list and filter the fields I needed. Here's my solution:

```
server.get('List', function (req, res, next) {

    var PaymentMgr = require('dw/order/PaymentMgr');

    var paymentMethods = PaymentMgr.getActivePaymentMethods();
    let paymentsResponse = [];

    const iterator = paymentMethods.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        let paymentMethod = iterator.next();
        paymentsResponse.push({id: paymentMethod.ID, name: paymentMethod.name, active: paymentMethod.active});
    }

    if (paymentMethods === undefined || paymentMethods === null) {
        res.json({
            message: 'failed to retrieve payment methods'
        });
    } else {
        res.json({
            paymentMethods: paymentsResponse
        });
    }
    
    next();
});
```

And here's the response with the payment methods:

[image]